# R plots' axis limits reset in Markdown

Tags: r, plot, markdown, r-markdown, render

The plot rendered in R Markdown doesn't use the axis limits I specified in the code.

```
plot(ansX1, ansY1, xlim=c(2,20), ylim=c(2,15))
abline(lm(ansY1 ~ ansX1))
```

Running this in RStudio generates a plot with the correct axis limits. When rendered in R Markdown, the x-axis limits are [-10,30].

Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?